# Python, Socket error: [Errno 111] when trying to create 2 servers within the same file

Tags: python, network-programming

I have to setup group communication between 2 groups using python sockets. Each group has a group leader which serves as a server to the other members of the group to transfer messages within the group. The 2 group leaders also need to communicate to transfer inter-group messages.

My program is working to transfer in-group messages. However to transfer inter-group messages, I have created a new thread on each leader (servers), and have one of the leaders as client, and the other as client.

Problem: My problem is that the I get a  "[Errno 111] Connection refused" error at the point where server 2 tries to connect to server 1.

Code (server 1) interGroupMsgSender function:

```
interGrpSock = socket.socket()        
interGrpSock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
host = socket.gethostname() 
port = 12349 
interGrpSock.bind((host, port))     
s.listen(1)  
clientSock, addr = s.accept()
# The other server has connected, handle sending messages
while(len(interGroupMsgs) > 0):
    msg = interGroupMsgs.pop(0)
    clientSock.send(msg);
```

Code (Server 2) interGroupMsgSender function:

```
ss = socket.socket()      
host = socket.gethostname() 
port = 12349 
try:
    ss.connect((host, port))
```

Code that creates a new thread (same for both servers):

```
thr2 = threading.Thread(target = interGroupMsgSender);
thr2.daemon=True  # Causes the thread to terminate when main process ends
thr2.start();
```

Note: Both of these servers already function as servers for the other group members.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are both servers are running on the same host?

Comment: Yes, both are on localhost actually.

Comment: Are server 1 starting to listen _before_ server 2 tries to connect? I also notice you only call `accept` once, will your "interGroupMsgSender" function in server 1 be called always before server 2 tries to connect?

Comment: Yes, server 1 is started and listening before I run server 2. Thanks for your interest to help btw :)

Comment: For server 1, where does `s` come from? It should be `interGrpSock.bind((host, port))`, and the same for the `accept` call. Can you post some repeatable code that we can run ourselves?

Comment: Thank you very very much Jay P, guess thats what I get for copying code and not properly reviewing it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer, given by JayP in a comment above, was a simple problem in the code. Due to me copying code and not reviewing it properly :(.

Server 1 code should be:

```
interGrpSock.bind((host, port))     
interGrpSock.listen(1)          /* Instead of s.listen(1) here */
```

Thank you again Jay P